# Grails - Layout is not getting applied after deploying to OC4J container

Tags: grails, oc4j

i am using grails 1.3.7. below is the snip of how i am applying the `customized` layout to my pages.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="layout" content="customized"/>
```

it is perfectly working when i run the application locally using `run-app` command.
However, after deploying the application to `OC4J`, layout is not getting applied and view is getting rendered without any required CSS and JS files. see the screenshot below:

[image]

**Edit:** List of plugins i am using along with versions:

- plugins.audit-logging=0.5.4
- plugins.calendar=1.2.1
- plugins.dynamic-jasper=0.6
- plugins.filterpane=2.0.1.1
- plugins.hibernate=1.3.7
- plugins.searchable=0.6.3
- plugins.spring-security-core=1.1.2
- plugins.spring-security-ldap=1.0.3
- plugins.tomcat=1.3.7
- plugins.tooltip=0.6

***any idea whats going wrong here??***

Comment: are you using the resources plugin or the asset-pipeline plugin? If so, I suspect that's where your problem lies

Comment: @Don: just added the list of plugins i am using along with versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the solution to above issue and decided to put it here as an answer. maybe it can help someone suffering from the same issue.

In my case, issue is related to JDK compliance level. On development machine, it was configured as 1.6 in eclipse IDE. And OC4J is using 1.5. So I did the following to get it working:

- changed the compiler compliance level of project is 1.5 in eclipse.
- configured the same version of JRE in my IDE which is used in my
  server machine by OC4J.